# MySQL Query, make ORDER BY rand() put a specific row in the bottom

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have an

```
ORDER BY rand()
```

SQL query for choosing a random row in my table, is there a possibilty to make so that it wont choose a specific row? For example, if I have a column called "Boolean" in the table, and I only want to have the

```
rand()
```

choose the rows where "Boolean" is equal to "1", and put the rest in the bottom, is that possible?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, or if Ive explained it badly, but Im pretty new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `order by`:

```
order by (boolean = 1) desc,
         rand()
```

`order by` can take more than one key value.  The first says to put values with `boolean = 1` first.  In a numeric context, a boolean expression is treated as a number, with `1` for true and `0` for false.  Hence the `desc` for the first expression.